# php array multidimensional search for bad words

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

im trying to search in an array for badwords.
my array looks like:

```
Array
(
    [base] => 2312783821823912
    [charset] => utf-8
    [Product] => Samsung PD291 Printer
    [meta] => Array
        (
            [description] => fucking nice Printer
            [keywords] => 
        )

    [n2] => Array
        (
            [w1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => printer
                )

            [w2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Menu
                    [1] => Main menu
                    [2] => Social
                    [3] => Speakers
                    [4] => 2015
                    [5] => Highlight
                    [6] => And... Action!
                    [7] => Short
                    [8] => Platin
                    [9] => Gold
                    [10] => Silber
                    [11] => Bronze
                    [12] => partner
                )

        )
}
```

I have an badword array like: $bad = array("fuck", "....);

Now im little bit confused what would be the fastest way to scan all values of the first array and return true or false if it contains badwords?

any advice would help ;-)

Thanks!

//edit:

Thanks @ everybody...
I will use:

```
class BadWordFilter {

    private static $bad = "/fuck|ass/i";

    public static function hasBadWords($input) {
        foreach ($input as $element) {
            if (is_array($element)) {
                if (self::hasBadWords($element)) {
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                if (preg_match(self::$bad, $element)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have tested it, and it will be the fastest solutions for my problem ;-))

Thanks everybody

Comment: 1. Have you tried something ? 2. *scan all values of the first array* <- Do you mean you only want to scan the first dimension of the array?

Comment: Use foreach loop and in_array function of PHP

Comment: oh, sorry i have forgotten :)

Comment: function badSearch($array,$search){
    foreach($array as $key=>$val){
        if(strpos($val, $badWords) !== false)return true;
        $x=badSearch($array[$key],$search);
    } return false;
}

Comment: nah, i would like to scan all dimensions of the first array

Comment: i think a nice way instead of walking through each dimension is to `json_encode` the array and scan the json string.

Comment: THANKS steven... this was so easy ;-)

Comment: @steven If you want you can put an answer in. I think this solved OP's problem and we have another happy ending.

Comment: @jimbo You may want to include your attempt into the question, by [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30072848/edit) it!

Comment: @Rizier123 yes i do. Give me a second please.

Comment: I don't like the idea of converting it into json. You are converting a large array into a string and then search for bad words in that string. I believe this is sub-optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a recursive search which ends its task when a bad word is found. Note, that converting it to json is sub-optimal, since you convert it into a string and then try to find the bad words in the string. It is time-consuming, especially if you have many arrays to check for bad words.

```
public class BadWordFilter {

    private static $bad = array(); //use your array instead

    public static function hasBadWords($input) {
        foreach ($element in $input) {
            if (is_array($element)) {
                if (self::hasBadWords($element)) {
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                foreach ($bad as $badWord) {
                    if(strpos($element, $badWord) !== false) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: you have a typo: `$in_array`

Comment: Thank you very much, @steven, you are perfectly right. I have edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I think the fastest way is to `json_encode` the array and scan the json string for the bad words.

Not tested but something like this should work:

```
 function badWordsExists($input_array, $blacklist){
    $jsonstring = json_encode($input_array);
    foreach($blacklist as $string) {
        if(strpos($jsonstring, $string) !== false) {
          return true;
        }
    }
    return false;  
}
```

Using regex should be faster but this is just an example to give you a idea how it may work.

Comment: As I have described, I believe this is a sub-optimal solution. Also, I believe you are over-complicating the task by having to pass the bad word array each time you are checking this. The set of bad words will not be changed frequently in my opinion.

Comment: @LajosArpad to pass the blacklist as array or having it as static var instead may be implemented by the OP. But i don't think that this is a big performance boost. The performance difference of converting it to json_string against walking recoursive through a n-dimensional array is very big as i think.

Comment: Note, that you are converting the whole array into a string, regardless of whether it contains ugly words or not. My solution finishes the search as long as the first ugly word is found. Also, your code converts it into a string even if the input does not have sub-arrays. After the comparison, you are searching for the ugly words one-by-one, which makes the algorithm stop when there is a first match in bad words.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive function is the answer here. The below code will detect any string in at any element of a given array.

```
<?php

function containsWord($haystack, $badWord)
{
    foreach ($haystack as $index => $item) {
        if (is_array($item)) {
            containsWord($item, $badWord);
        } else {
            if (strpos($item, $badWord) !== false) {
                echo "'$badWord' has been detected in '$item' at index '$index'";
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    echo "$badWord is not in the array";
    return false;
}

$array = [1 => [4=> 'badword', 5=> 'qw'], 2 => 'b', 3 => 'c'];

containsWord($array, 'bad');
```

The output of the above code will be:
`'bad' has been detected in 'badword' at index '4'`

Hope this helps :)